# Two apps in review in publish - how to know which one will be published?

Tags: google-play, release

I'm in the following situation:

[image]

Both versions are in the "review and publish" state, definitely not out to the public yet

I want to release just one, the one that says 176(1.0.27)

How can I be sure that when i click review and publish only that one will be published, and the other one will be archived?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `176(1.0.27)` one is currently at 0%. You can [increase staged rollout percentage](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6346149?hl=en#zippy=%2C%E6%AE%B5%E9%9A%8E%E7%9A%84%E3%81%AA%E5%85%AC%E9%96%8B%E3%81%AE%E5%89%B2%E5%90%88%E3%82%92%E5%BC%95%E3%81%8D%E4%B8%8A%E3%81%92%E3%82%8B%2Cselect-staged-rollout-percentage%2Cincrease-your-staged-rollout-percentage) to 25% or something. Once it has reached at 100% and wait a couple hours for it to take effect, I think the older version will be closed.

Comment: that did not work

Comment: @LenaBru Did you manually increase it to 100%?

Comment: yes - thid comment is not long enough so i have to add unnecessary text to make it long enough

Comment: add to the answer: "And wait a couple hours for it to take effect" and i will accept it.

Comment: @LenaBru I updated my answer. Is it ok?